# Python inverted dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm currently writing a function that takes a dictionary with immutable values and returns an inverted dictionary. So far, my code is getting extremely simple tests right, but it still has some kinks to work out

```
def dict_invert(d):

     inv_map = {v: k for k, v in d.items()}

     return inv_map

     list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
     list2 = {[1]:3245,[2]:4356,[3]:6578}
     d = {['a']:[],['b']:[]}
     d['a'].append(list1)
     d['b'].append(list2)
```

How do I fix my code so that it passes the test cases?

My only thoughts are to change list 2 to `[1:32, 2:43, 3:54, 4:65]`; however, I would still have a problem with having the `"[]"` in the right spot. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: What's with the all the stuff after your return statement?

Comment: Your oddly-named `list2` and your `d` shouldn't even run: lists aren't hashable, so you can't use them as dictionary keys.

Comment: @DSM -- That was my first thought too, but If they really are after the return statement, then they _don't_ run (which might explain why some of the tests pass?)

Comment: Use `collections.defaultdict`

Comment: @mgilson you got it!

Comment: @JBernardo defaultdict alone doesn't do the job, since the fundamental issue of K0 -> V0, K1 -> V0, K2 -> V0 inverting into V0 -> [K0, K1, K2] isn't solved without a bit of additional logic (which the tests seem to want...)

Comment: @mgilson: I wondered if they weren't part of the function but were building inputs to the function.  You're probably right, though.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to realize that multiple keys can have the same values, so when inverting, you must make sure your values map to a list of keys.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def dict_invert(d):
  inv_map = defaultdict(list)
  for k, v in d.items():
    inv_map[v].append(k)
  return inv_map
```

**EDIT:**

Just adding a bit of more helpful info...

The `defaultdict(list)` makes the default value of the dict = `list()` when accessed via `[]` or `get` (when normally it would raise `KeyError` or return `None` respectively).

With that defaultdict in place, you can use a bit of logic to group keys together... here's an example to illustrate (from my comment above)

Original dict: K0 -> V0, K1 -> V0, K2 -> V0

Should invert to: V0 -> [K0, K1, K2]

**EDIT 2:**

Your tests seem to be forcing you into using a normal dict, in which case...

```
def dict_invert(d):
    inv_map = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v not in inv_map: 
            inv_map[v] = []
        inv_map[v].append(k)
     return inv_map
```

Comment: Now it's outputting defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {}) for every test. Any idea why it's doing that? Do i need to add a dict.get?